# What is the flaw in this proof that uses induction?

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics

Find the flaw in the following proof that $a^n = 1$ for all non-negative integers $n$, whenever $a$ is a non-zero real number.

> **Proof:** $P(n)\!:\ \forall k \leq n,\ a^n = 1$  where k is non-negative integer valued variable.
>
> **Base case:** $P(0)$ is equivalent to $a^0 = 1$, which is true.
>
> **Inductive step:** By induction hypothesis, $a^k = 1\ \forall k \in \mathbb N\ \mbox{s.t.}\ k \leq n$
> **But then**
> $$a^{n + 1} = \frac{a^n\cdot a^n}{a^{n-1}} = \frac{1\cdot1}1 = 1$$
> which implies that $P(n+1)$ holds!

Comment: I've edited your post. Please use MathJax in the future: [here is a tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Please do not vandalise your question.

Comment: Nick. A friendly message from your friendly community moderator. Do not deface your post by removing essential parts or radical edits. A site rule (that you implicitly agreed to by posting). Doing that is disrespectful to those users who donated their time answering your question - not forgetting future readers who may benefit from the exchanges.

Answer (score 5):

The flaw is that the value of $a^{n-1}$ is not covered by your base case for n=0

Answer (score 4):

How do you go from $n=0$ (which holds) to $n=1$ (which does not) using your inductive step? You are dividing by $a^{n-1}=a^{0-1}$, for which you haven't proved anything.